# Neo4J: Compare a property value gathered with "order by Limit 1" with a property value of another label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There are two labels Car and Session. The Sessions are ordered descending with limit 1 to get the latests Session. This latest Session has one playerVehicleIdx as property. This exact playerVehicleIdx should be matched with the right vehicleIdx of the Cars available.

Idea:

```
MATCH (m:Car) with (n:Session) Return n ORDER BY n.sessionStart DESC LIMIT 1 
WHERE n.playerVehicleIdx = m.vehicleIdx RETURN m,n
```

The query is wrong and i tried many different variants that did not work as well.
How to fix the query to compare the property value of the one node that comes from the sorting of the Sessions with the property value of the Cars?

Comment: what is PacketSessionData_V1? You mentioned Car and Session, so what is the relationship between car and session?  What is your input parameter?  Do you want to list all cars with the lastest session playerVehicleId?  Also you cannot have two RETURN in one query statement.

Comment: I forgot to edit it right, PacketSessionData_V1 = Session here. I want to list all Cars, but the vehicleIdx is unique and the Session only holds one value for playerVehicleIdx, so it should be unique. It is correct now.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should create a relationship between Car and Session using vehicleIdx.  Then run below query:

```
// Get all car and session
MATCH (c:Car)--(s:Session)
// Group by car, get the latest session based on sessionStart
WITH c, collect(s)[0] as s ORDER BY s.sessionStart DESC 
// When there are more than 1 session per car, it will get the top session record  where [0] is the index of the first record
RETURN c, s
```

Comment: Thank you! Now i get the latest session. For another usecase  i need the s.playerVehicleIdx from the returned session and find this in the label CarMotionData. So i need to compare s.playerVehicleIdx = CarMotionData.vehicleIdx which are not connected directly.
Something like that did not work: 

MATCH (c:CarMotionData)--(l:Lap)--(s:Session) 
WITH c, collect(s)[0] as s ORDER BY s.sessionStart DESC 
where s.playerVehicleIdx = c.vehicleIdx 
RETURN c,s

Comment: Question; how are CarMotionData connected to Session? If not by vehicleIdx then your logic in the where clause will NOT work and it will return no data.  If Car and Session are connected by vehicle index then you don't need the where clause.